# how can i reduce those propositions?

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

how to i reduce the below compound propositions ?

1) (p∨q∨¬r)∧(p∨¬q∨¬s)∧(p∨¬r∨¬s)∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬s)

2) (¬p∨¬q∨r)∧(¬p∨q∨¬s)∧(p∨¬q∨ ¬s) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s)

3) (p∨q∨r)∧(p∨¬q∨¬s)∧(q∨¬r∨s) ∧ (¬p∨r∨s)∧(¬p∨q∨¬s)∧(p∨¬q∨¬r) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ s) ∧
(¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s)

i tried applying DeMorgan's law and key logical equivalences with no luck, as i proceeded things got pretty messed up and couldn't end up with a logical answer.

Comment: What do you know about tautologies?

Comment: all their values are true.

Comment: @Predator44 Right so if there is a negation and at least one truth in an "or" statement, it is safe to say that the statement is true. It's false for "and" statements if there is at least one negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key, here, is making use of the distributive laws:

$$P \lor (Q \land R) \iff [(P \lor Q) \land (P \land Q)]\tag{A}$$

$$P \land (Q \lor R) \iff [(P \land Q) \lor (P\land R)]\tag{B}$$

I'll get you started on (1), making use of $(A)$ repeatedly, plus a few key identities:

$$(1)\quad (p∨q∨¬r)∧(p∨¬q∨¬s)∧(p∨¬r∨¬s)∧ (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬s)$$

$$\equiv [(p \lor q) \lor (\lnot r \land \lnot s)] \land [(\lnot q \lor \lnot s) \lor \underbrace{(p \land \lnot p)}_{\text{false}}] \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot s)$$

$$\equiv [(p \lor q) \lor (\lnot r \land \lnot s)] \land (\lnot q \lor \lnot s) \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot s)$$

$$\equiv [(p\lor q) \lor (\lnot r \land \lnot s)] \land (\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor \lnot s)\tag{absorption}$$

$$\equiv \;\cdots $$

Comment: Let me know if there is anything in particular I can address or clarify.

Comment: is this right? thanks in advance :)

Comment: (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r)∧(¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s)

≡(¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) ∧(p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s)

≡(¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (¬r ∨ ¬s) ∨ (p∧ ¬p)

≡(¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (¬r ∨ ¬s)

Comment: I'll take a closer look at it a little later, okay? Getting close to my dinner time! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Very nice write up +1